# Need MySQL db for php script

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a shop for my website, so I need MySQL.
I want to take 50 Golds from the user, and give 5 atkdmg.
My current script looks like this:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
print('<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" 
/>');
include('config.php');

if(isset($_SESSION['rank']) && $_SESSION['rank'] >= 1)
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['Gold']) && $_SESSION['Gold'] >= 50)
    {
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET Gold = $_SESSION[Gold]-50 WHERE id = 
$_SESSION[id];");
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET AtkDmg = $_SESSION[AtkDmg] + 5' WHERE id = 
$_SESSION[id];");
    } else header('location: shop.php');
} else header('location: login.php');
mysql_close()
?>
```

What is session? here it is:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

include('config.php');
include('login_form.php');

   if(isset($_POST["login"])){

   $nickname = $_POST["nickname"];
   $password = md5($_POST["password"]);
   $lekerdezes = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE nickname = 
'".mysql_real_escape_string($nickname)."' AND password = '$password'");
   $vanelekerdezes = mysql_num_rows($lekerdezes);
   if ($vanelekerdezes>0)
   {
      header('location: login.php');
      $adatok=mysql_fetch_assoc($lekerdezes);
      $_SESSION["id"]=$adatok["id"];
      $_SESSION['bann'] = 0;
      $_SESSION["nickname"]=$adatok["nickname"];
      $_SESSION["rank"]=$adatok["rank"];      
      $_SESSION["Gold"]=$adatok["Gold"];
      $_SESSION["AtkDmg"]=$adatok["AtkDmg"];
  }
   else
  {
   print 'Hibás felhasználónév vagy jelszó!';
   print mysql_error();
  }



   } else if(isset($_SESSION["nickname"])){


   header('location: home.php');
   }



?>
```

I hope you can help me, I'm still learning PHP, so maybe that's why I can't fix this simple thing... So if you would write: learn PHP, I'm already doing that :)

Comment: Sooo... What's the problem? Are you getting any errors? Maybe take a quick peek at [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ?

Comment: It is not doing anything, I get a blank page, sorry for the bad question.

Comment: `mysql_*` api is deprecated try to use `mysqli_* or pdo`

Comment: I use 5.4 PHP where it can still be used.

Comment: If your getting blank page means .your code have some errors . so put this two lines in top of page .to debug the error .`ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` @hunzeno

Comment: Ok, I tested some things, it says no errors, but now it takes 50 gold, and It is not giving me +5 atkdmg.

Comment: Please stop using this ancient and insecure API

Comment: Yes, look into using PDO for your DB connections http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, adjust the session var:

```
$gold = $_SESSION['Gold'] = $_SESSION['Gold'] - 50;
$attackDamage = $_SESSION['AtkDmg'] = $_SESSION['AtkDmg'] + 5;
```

Edit your SQL strings like this:

```
"UPDATE users SET AtkDmg = $attackDamage etc etc
```

Comment: It sets my gold and atkdmg to 0.

Comment: Works perfect, ty so much, you are the best!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! :-)